# how to convert array with keys/values to JSON c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json

I'm completey new to C# and I've already given myself a headache. I know this is probably kids stuff to you, but I've spent an hour+ googleing around and can't seem to work it out.

All I'm trying to do is convert an array into JSON. I know PHP well, so here's an example of what I'm trying to do (in PHP):

```
$myarr=array("key1"=>"value for key 1","key2"=>"value for key 2");

$jsonArray=json_encode($myarr);
```

so `$jsonArray` will be: `{"key1":"value for key 1","key2":"value for key 2"}`

Now, I'm trying to do exactly that, but in C#.

This is what I have so far:

```
 String[] keys = new String[] { "emailSend","toEmail"};
 String[] values = new String[] {textBox2.Text,textBox1.Text};
 JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string json = js.Serialize(keys);//final json result
 MessageBox.Show(json);//show me
```

I'm using Visual Studio C# 2010, which is throwing this error (with the code above):

> The type or namespace name 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a correct `using` statement? Add the following to the top of your file:

`using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

**EDIT**: To get correctly formatted JSON, use a `Dictionary` instead:

```
var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
               {
                   { "emailSend", textBox1.Text },
                   { "toEmail", textBox2.Text }
               };

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(keyValues);
MessageBox.Show(json);
```

Comment: This is in System.Web.Extensions.dll in case you don't have it loaded as a reference (i.e.; a winforms or wpf project wouldn't have it by default).  You may choose to use something like [fastJSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON).  Serializing objects is even easier and faster than using JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: I now get the error: `The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` thanks xD

Comment: @nav_nav Hmm, strange. Are you using pre .NET 3.5?

Comment: Don't think I am. How would I check?

Comment: Ok, to check you right click on your project in the Solution Explorer (tree on the right in Visual Studio) and select Properties. From there, click on the "Application" tab on the left hand side and make sure your Target Framework is 3.5 or above.

Comment: @nav_nav Add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions.dll`

Comment: @L.B Yeah you just beat me to that LOL. If your framework is in the correct version, add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.dll by right clicking on your project, selecting add reference, going to the .NET tab and locating System.Web.Extensions and pressing Ok. To make it easier to find in that list, if you click on Component name in the .NET tab it will sort them alphabetically :)

Comment: @nav_nav looks like you'll definitely need to add that reference then (see my comment above your last one)

Comment: `System.Web.Extensions` is not in that list. I have `System.Web.Services` and `System.Web.ApplicationServices` but no `System.Web.Entensions` :S

Comment: Eh? :S. What kind of project is it?

Comment: @mattytommo Okay so I googled around and I found that I have to change my framework to 4 (instead of 4 client profile) and its all working. But, just one problem: When testing, I get: `[ "emailSend","toEmail"]` as the JSON result when it should be `[ "emailSend":"sometext","toEmail":"sometext"]`

Comment: Check my edit I've provided you with the code you need for that, you'll need to use a dictionary instead to get it in that format.

Comment: @nav_nav No problems :) glad I could help.

Comment: What is the library for .Net Core 3.0?

Answer (score 16):

how about using JSON.NET and the JObject class?

```
var obj = new JObject();

obj["One"] = "Value One";
obj["Two"] = "Value Two";
obj["Three"] = "Value Three";

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

gives you

```
{"One":"Value One","Two":"Value Two","Three":"Value Three"}
```

Comment: With that, I get: `The type or namespace name 'JObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and `The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: In case of *JObject not found*, you need to add 'using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;' library.