# How to pass an array to a string.Format() string when construct a Json string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string.format

My code is below:

```
string requestBody = string.Format(
             @"{{
                   ""RequestServerVersion"":""2016.04.05"",
                   ""PreferredDate"":""{0}"",
                   ""StaffList"":""{1}""
               }}",
             preferredDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
             "test");
```

StaffList is a string array, If I pass a single string like "test", it won't work. How do I pass a string array to it in the string.Format(...)? Since in the server side, StaffList is handled as a string Array.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can convert your array content to JSON string and then pass it to String.Format. See the last answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387382/how-to-convert-array-with-keys-values-to-json-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid rolling your own JSON when there are good libraries for making sure it works properly.

Try this with `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
string[] staffList = new [] { "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie" };
DateTime preferredDate = DateTime.Now;

var data = new
{
    RequestServerVersion = "2016.04.05",
    PreferredDate = preferredDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    StaffList = staffList,
};

string requestBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "RequestServerVersion":"2016.04.05",
    "PreferredDate":"2016-04-05",
    "StaffList":["Alice","Bob","Charlie"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that come into my mind:

1. Try to join the Array to a single string using string.Join() and split the string on serverside using string.Split()
2. Use the JSON Arrays Syntax in your code, Loop over each Array index and insert them one by one in this syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

BTW: Have you considered to use **Serialization** instead of building your JSON on your own?

Comment: Thanks, Jannik. I will close this question by marking it answered.

Comment: Glad I could help.